# Eclipse Check for Updates does nothing

Tags: eclipse

I am currently using eclipse 4.7.0 and version 4.7.1 is out, So when I click check for updates nothing happens.

Any idea why ? Please Help

Comment: It might take some time if some of the update sites are slow. Check the status line or/and the _Progress_ view if updates are downloaded in the background after you triggered _Help > Check for Updates_.

Comment: Well it works only when I use java not with eclipse CDT anyways the problem is solved